# How to diagnose file upload failures in SilverStripe running on Apache

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, silverstripe

I am facing a pretty common situation judging from the questions either here on SO or in the SilverStripe forums: file uploads fail.

However, my situation seems to stem from an issue that I haven't met yet on the Web; from reading other questions and many blog articles or forum threads, I have ruled out:

- Permission problems
- `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in the PHP configuration (both set to 8M)
- `LimitRequestBody` in the Apache Configuration (default value of 0, meaning "unlimited")

I have ruled these out for many reasons but this picture shows with an example of three consecutive uploads that the uploads are sometimes working:

[image: Screenshot of the file upload page in SilverStripe]

I have also [started a thread](https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/118588) on the SilverStripe forums for this problem, but I have little hope of having luck solving the problem there.

I have set up breakpoints in the `Upload`, `UploadField` and `File` classes, and stepped through the code for hours without succeeding in identifying the cause of the error.

My finding so far is that any file above 128 kiB causes an internal server error. Any file below this size threshold gets uploaded as expected.

All logs (Apache, PHP, SilverStripe) are totally mute when this error occurs.

A permission issue seems very unlikely because:

- PHP runs in Fast-CGI mode as a user (`web1`) created by ISPConfig
- Apache runs as user `apache:apache`
- I have added `apache` to the group of user so that `groups web1` gives me `web1 : client1 sshusers` and `groups apache` gives me `apache : apache ispapps ispconfig client1`
- the upload folder (`assets`) is owned by `web1:client1` and has permissions 775
- the temporary upload folder (`upload_tmp_dir`) is owned by `web1:client1` and permissions are 775.

I believe what I'm looking is a means of somehow getting information about where and why the uploads fail. Is it possible to set the loglevel of Apache to "debug" or "trace"?

NOTE: an entry in the "Similar Questions" led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8971564/2749913), which hints at `SSLRenegBufferSize` being by default at exactly 128 kiB. Unfortunately, whether the protocol is HTTPS or HTTP has no influence: the problem shows up.

[EDIT] I had later on set the `LogLevel` directive to `trace` but I still had no message about this error in the server logs.

Comment: Have you checked `phpinfo()` to see if your configuration is properly applied (eg. the max upload settings)?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I checked. The value I've reported in the first bullet point list comes from phpinfo.

Comment: Quick google brought me to this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300301/debian-jessie-apache2-php-5-6-cant-upload-more-than-128kbr) and [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-upload-images-larger-than-128kb-http-error) that suggests checking the `FcgidMaxRequestLen` value. You should be definitely be seeing error logs appearing.

Comment: Id bet you get the same behavior if you create a simple php form to upload files your self so a server configuration issue is more like to be the origin of the issue.

Comment: @FinBoWa: could you post your comment as an answer? `FcgidMaxRequestLen` was indeed the culprit. Changing the value solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick googling took me to the following articles:

- [Debian Jessie - Apache2 / PHP 5.6, can't upload more than 128kb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300301/debian-jessie-apache2-php-5-6-cant-upload-more-than-128kb)
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-upload-images-larger-than-128kb-http-error

Those suggest to check `FcgidMaxRequestLen` setting value.

This doesn't answer how to debug that correctly but helps solve the original issue.